# openMP implementation of loop until predicate met

Tags: c++, algorithm, openmp

I want to implement in openMP a loop that terminates when a certain condition holds. In serial code the function body would simply be

```
for(; begin < end; ++begin)
    if(pred(begin))
        return true;
return false;
```

The openMP version may differ in two respects: (1) concurrent function calls to `pred()` are not truncated and (2) the order of calls to `pred()` may be anything. However, it must not be assumed that calls to `pred()` are all equally expensive.

```
/// loop until pred(i) returns true;
/// \return  whether loop was terminated
template<typename index, typename predicate>
bool loop_until(index begin, index end, predicate const&pred)
{
    const index chunk_size = std::max(index(1), index((begin-end)/(8*omp_get_num_threads())));
    std::atomic<bool>  stop{false};
    std::atomic<index> next_chunk{begin};
#   pragma omp parallel
    {
        for(index beg_chunk = next_chunk.fetch_add(chunk_size);
            beg_chunk < end && !stop;
            beg_chunk = next_chunk.fetch_add(chunk_size))
            for(index end_chunk = std::min(beg_chunk+chunk_size,end);
                beg_chunk < end_chunk && !stop;
                ++beg_chunk)
                if(pred(beg_chunk))
                    stop = true;
    }
    return stop;    
}
```

I'm a bit rusty on openMP hence my questions:

- Is the code correct?
- Is there a more openMPish or better way to code this?